# Custom character for input

Tags: primefaces

I am new to java, I am working with primefaces and as part of a capture for username I am being asked for this.

How can I customize the capture? You can capture numbers (0-9) and letters (a-zA-Z) but I also require: # $ & -_. How can I make special characters for this? Thanks in advance and an apology in case I do not ask the question correctly.

I already made several tests but I do not have the desired result. When I put the "&" character it marks me an error leaving it like this:

```xml
    <o:validator 
        validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression"
        pattern="^[#$-_.A-Za-z0-9\\+]+(\\.[#$-_.A-Za-z0-9]+)*" 
        message="La contraseña no tiene un formato válido." />

    <p:outputLabel value="Contraseña:" for="newUserPwd1"/>
        <p:password  
        id="newUserPwd1" value="#{userManagerView.pass1}" required="true"
        requiredMessage ="La contraseña es obligatoria.">
        <o:validator 
        validatorId="javax.faces.Length" minimum="6" 
        message="La contraseña requiere mínimo de 6 caracteres"/>
        <o:validator 
        validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression"
        pattern="^[#$-_.A-Za-z0-9\\+]+(\\.[#$-_.A-Za-z0-9]+)*" 
        message="La contraseña no tiene un formato válido." />
    </p:password>
```

This is the error with the character &

> Parsing Error /viewMetadata/admin/usuarios.xhtml: Error Traced [line: 172] A decimal representation must appear immediately after "& #
>   Caused by:
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException - Error Parsing /viewMetadata/admin/usuarios.xhtml: Error Traced [line: 172] A decimal representation must appear immediately after "& #
>   at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompileViewMetadata (SAXCompiler.java:838)

Comment: Errors are very good search engine terms. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info (but this is true in general, not only jsf)

Comment: Oh and the regexp's are in OmniFaces not PrimeFaces, but the issue is facelets... But a regexp which cause the error as the **only** child of `<h:body>` So `<h:body>^[#$-_.A-Za-z0-9\\+]+(\\.[#$-_.A-Za-z0-9]+)*</h:body>` Same error, right? That is creating a [mcve], reduce, remove etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do ampersands (&) need to be encoded in JSF? Is there a way around this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086709/why-do-ampersands-need-to-be-encoded-in-jsf-is-there-a-way-around-this)