# allow "&" character in primefaces keyfilter

Tags: regex, primefaces, el, keyfilter

I would need a regex that allows the **&** character in primefaces keyfilter for a p:autocomplete field

My current keyFilter looks like this:

```
<p:keyFilter for="xyzComponent" preventPaste="false" regEx="/[A-Za-z-ÁÀȦÂÄǞǍĂĀÃÅǺǼǢĆĊĈČĎḌḐḒÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒẼE̊ẸǴĠĜǦĞG̃ĢĤḤáàȧâäǟǎăāãåǻǽǣćċĉčďḍḑḓéèėêëěĕēẽe̊ẹǵġĝǧğg̃ģĥḥÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨỊĴĶǨĹĻĽĿḼM̂M̄ʼNŃN̂ṄN̈ŇN̄ÑŅṊÓÒȮȰÔÖȪǑŎŌÕȬŐỌǾƠíìiîïǐĭīĩịĵķǩĺļľŀḽm̂m̄ŉńn̂ṅn̈ňn̄ñņṋóòôȯȱöȫǒŏōõȭőọǿơP̄ŔŘŖŚŜṠŠȘṢŤȚṬṰÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮỤẂẀŴẄÝỲŶŸȲỸŹŻŽẒǮp̄ŕřŗśŝṡšşṣťțṭṱúùûüǔŭūũűůụẃẁŵẅýỳŷÿȳỹźżžẓǯßœŒçÇ0-9! \/ \.\?_-]/i"/>
```

i tried & and \& inside the "[]", but I get the following error:

```
Error Parsing xyz.xhtml : Error Traced[line: 82] The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

Comment: Found multiple results when searching for '[jsf] ampersand' - maybe my dup is not the best. This one is good either: [Why do ampersands (&) need to be encoded in JSF? Is there a way around this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086709/why-do-ampersands-need-to-be-encoded-in-jsf-is-there-a-way-around-this#11090043)

Comment: thanks, adding "&amp;" inside the "[]" worked